# How to show differences between columns of two csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files:

```
old file:

name    size_bytes
air unknown
data/air/monitor    
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region   
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region   
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02    
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/EN 
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/EN/datapackage.json    886
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/EN/digest.txt  186
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/EN/JOSM_AMS13_SpecHg_AB_2017-04-02_EN.pdf  9033
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/FR 
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/FR/datapackage.json    886
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/FR/digest.txt  186
...


new file:

name    size_bytes
data    0
data/air    0
data/air/monitor    0
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region   0
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/96c679c3-709e-4a42-89c6-09f09f2b7ffe.xml  65589
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/datapackage.json  13152367
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/digest.txt    188
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region   0
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02    0
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/FR 0
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/FR/JOSM_AMS13_SpecHg_AB_2017-04-02_FR.pdf  9186
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-02/digest.txt 82
data/air/monitor/ambient-air-quality-oil-sands-region/ecosystem-sites-speciated-mercury-preliminary-data-oil-sands-region/2017-04-09    0
...
```

I want to compare the names from the "old file" to the names in the "new file" and get any missing names (folder or file paths).

Right now I have this:

```
with open('old_file.csv', 'r') as old_file:
    old = set(row.split(',')[0].strip().lower() for row in old_file)

with open('new_file.csv','r') as new_file, open('compare.csv', 'w') as compare_files:
    for line in new_file:
        if line.split(',')[0].strip().lower() not in old:
            compare_files.write(line)
```

This runs but the output is not correct, it prints out names that ARE in both files.
Here is the output:

```
data    0
data/air    0
data/air/monitor/deposition-oil-sands-region/the-monitored-ambient-concentration-and-estimated-atmospheric-deposition-of-trace-elements-at-four-monitoring-sites-in-the-canadian-athabasca-oil-sands-region 0
data/air/monitor/deposition-oil-sands-region/the-monitored-ambient-concentration-and-estimated-atmospheric-deposition-of-trace-elements-at-four-monitoring-sites-in-the-canadian-athabasca-oil-sands-region/ElementConcentrationPM25_OSM_AMS-sites_2016-2017.csv    736737
data/air/monitor/deposition-oil-sands-region/the-monitored-ambient-concentration-and-estimated-atmospheric-deposition-of-trace-elements-at-four-monitoring-sites-in-the-canadian-athabasca-oil-sands-region/ElementConcentrationPM25to10_OSM_AMS-sites_2016-2017.csv    227513
data/air/monitor/deposition-oil-sands-region/the-monitored-ambient-concentration-and-estimated-atmospheric-deposition-of-trace-elements-at-four-monitoring-sites-in-the-canadian-athabasca-oil-sands-region/ElementFlux_OSM_AMS-sites_2016-2017.csv 691252
data/air/monitor/deposition-oil-sands-region/the-monitored-ambient-concentration-and-estimated-atmospheric-deposition-of-trace-elements-at-four-monitoring-sites-in-the-canadian-athabasca-oil-sands-region/ffeae500-ea0c-493f-9b24-5efbd16411fd.xml    41399
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-atmospheric-precipitation-chemistry/major-ions/AtmosphericPrecipitationChemistry-MajorIons-APQMP-AllSites-2019.csv   169109
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-atmospheric-precipitation-chemistry/major-ions/AtmosphericPrecipitationChemistry-MajorIons-APQMP-AllSites-2020.csv   150205
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-atmospheric-precipitation-chemistry/major-ions/AtmosphericPrecipitationChemistry-MajorIons-CAPMoN-AllSites-2017.csv  4343972
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-atmospheric-precipitation-chemistry/major-ions/AtmosphericPrecipitationChemistry-MajorIons-CAPMoN-AllSites-2018.csv  3782783
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases 0
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2012.csv   1826690
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2013.csv   1890761
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2014.csv   1946788
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2015.csv   2186536
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2016.csv   2434692
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2017.csv   2150499
data/air/monitor/monitoring-of-combined-atmospheric-gases-and-particles/major-ions-and-acidifying-gases/AtmosphericCombinedGasesParticles-FilterPack-CAPMoN-AllSites-2018.csv   2136853
...
```

Is there something wrong with my code?
Is there a better way to do this? Maybe using pandas?

Comment: Using `row.split(',')` only works if the fields in the row are separated by commas. In your files, they are not. You probably wanted `row.split()`, which will split on whitespace.

Comment: I assumed all csv's were comma separated

Comment: indeed. But those files aren't CSVs. If they were, you'd see the commas when you look at the files. I suppose those files are tab-separated, although it's hard to tell just looking at them since tabs look a lot like spaces. Sometimes people use the `.csv` extension for tab-separated files (or semicolon-separated files, or even `|`-separated files) but that doesn't change the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your tags mention `Pandas` but I don't see you using it. Either way, an outer merge should do what you want, if I understand your question:

```py
old = pd.read_csv(path_to_old_file)
new = pd.read_csv(path_to_new_file)

df = pd.merge(old, new, on="name", how="outer")
```

Your post isn't super clear on what exactly you need, and I don't particularly feel like scrutinizing those file names for differences. From what I could gather, you want *all* the unique file paths from both csv files, right? It's not clear what you want done with the other column so I've left them alone.

I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) Stack Overflow post.

### EDIT

After your clarification:

```py
old = pd.read_csv(path_to_old_file)
new = pd.read_csv(path_to_new_file)

np.setdiff1d(old["name"], new["name"])
```

This will give you all the values in the `name` column of the `old` dataframe which are *not present* in the `new` dataframe.

Comment: Basically I want a list of the names that are in the old file, but are missing in the new file. I guess I should make that more clear in my question.

Comment: So the old file has 44k rows, the new file has 31k rows, and the df created with your code has 64k rows. What I want would have to be smaller than the 44k rows of the old file. I want to know what is missing in the new file, that was in the old file. Is that outer-left? Is it because it's checking for matching index number too?

Comment: See my update @Mitch